# How to determine whether a particular website is built with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I saw a Chinese technology website, but I'm not sure if it's developed using WordPress.

Is the website leixue.com built using the WordPress program?

How to determine and view it?

Answer (score 0):

Do View Source on the page, then look for images and scripts etc with URLs with `/wp-content/` in them.